Having trouble wrapping text in a grid on the 3rd text line versus first
this is my first time using a grid layout. I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to wrap text on the 3rd line versus how it appears now on the first.
This is how it looks now:
Current Grid - Image
I'd love to achieve this result:
Desired Grid - Image
Here's the current HTML:
<ul class="grid">
    <li class="grid__item">
        <h3>Week 1</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">Course Welcome and Orientation</a></h4>
    </li>
    <li class="grid__item">
        <h3>Week 2</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">Landscapes of Early Cultures</a></h4>
    </li>
    <li class="grid__item">
        <h3>Week 3</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">The Enlightened Landscape: Western Europe in the 15th and 16th Centuries</a></h4>
    </li>
</ul>

Here's the accompanying CSS:
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0px 0 50px 0;
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
      }

.grid__item {
  background: #2774ae;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  min-height: 190px;
  
  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    background-color: #005587 !important;
  }

  a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
   color: #ffffff !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
  }


  h4 {
    font-size: 1.05rem !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    margin: 1rem 1.5rem !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  max-width: 190px;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  


}

h4 a {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

h4 a:hover,
h4 a:focus {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

h4 a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
transition: background-color 0.1s ease-out;
    background-color: transparent; }

  
  h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.05rem !important;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0.25rem 1.5rem !important;
}
  
  h3:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 55px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #FFD100;
  margin: 1rem 0 0.7rem 0;
  border-radius: 99px;
}


  ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0 !important;
}

ul li {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}

}

I've exhausted so many options. Unfortunately, I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Remove display: -webkit-box on the h4 and both of the display: inline-block on the a element inside the h4. The issue is nothing to do with Grid layout.

@ralph.m Thank you so much! This seemed to do the trick in adding the ellipses and truncating the text, but just one minor issue left. Is there a way I can have it add the ellipses and truncate the text on the third line of text versus the first? (Like in the "Desired Grid- Image" Above.)

Remove the white-space: nowrap css attribute from your .h4 class. Also remove display: inline-block from a couple of spots, and change min-height to height for .grid__item.
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0px 0 50px 0;
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
      }

.grid__item {
  background: #2774ae;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 190px; /* change this to height */
  
  &:hover,
  &:focus-within {
    background-color: #005587 !important;
  }

  a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
   /* display: inline-block;*/
   color: #ffffff !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
  }


  h4 {
    font-size: 1.05rem !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    margin: 1rem 1.5rem !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
 /*   white-space: nowrap;*/
  display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  max-width: 190px;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  


}

h4 a {
    position: static;
 /*   display: inline-block !important;*/
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

h4 a:hover,
h4 a:focus {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

h4 a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
transition: background-color 0.1s ease-out;
    background-color: transparent; }

  
  h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.05rem !important;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0.25rem 1.5rem !important;
}
  
  h3:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 55px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #FFD100;
  margin: 1rem 0 0.7rem 0;
  border-radius: 99px;
}


  ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0 !important;
}

ul li {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}

}


Thanks @nardnob ! I tried this earlier, but it didn't quite work. What I see when I do this is the entire title appears pushing the grid height down for all boxes, versus seeing the ellipses truncate the title on the 3rd line. For longer titles, it just stretched out multiple lines extending the grid height.

@VeeSands I see what you mean. I updated my answer to also use height instead of min-height for .grid-item, and I removed display:inline-block from a couple of spots. Try that out and see if it works for you.

Works like a charm! @nardnob Thank you SO much! I spent hours yesterday trying so many different solutions and it just didn't hit. Thanks, appreciate your help on this one!
